# Slide Down Pop Up OS X Swift

Tags: swift, macos

I am trying to display a slide down item so that I can obtain some user input, but I'm brand new to OS X coding and not sure what I have to do in order to get this to display, I want it to look like this drop down from iCloud system preferences.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a regular [NSWindow](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/) being displayed as a **sheet** on top of another window. You can present one using the NSWindow method [`beginSheet(_:completionHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/beginSheet:completionHandler:).

You can read more in the [Sheet Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Sheets/Sheets.html) document and the [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/OSXHIGuidelines/WindowDialogs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000957-CH43-SW1).